# Unable to start the Amazon SSM Agent - failed to start message bus

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

When registering an Amazon SSM Agent, it registers successfully in the SSM Managed Instances console, but the connection shows "Connection Lost".

When I try to start the service manually, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred fetching the seelog config file path:  open /etc/amazon/ssm/seelog.xml: no such file or directory
Initializing new seelog logger
New Seelog Logger Creation Complete
2020-12-09 10:20:01 ERROR error occurred when starting amazon-ssm-agent: failed to start message bus, failed to start health channel: failed to listen on the channel: ipc:///var/lib/amazon/ssm/ipc/health, address in use
```

How exactly do I solve this? I've tried to restart the service a few times but no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by stopping the agent and purging the /var/lib/amazon/ssm/ipc directory

```
service amazon-ssm-agent stop
rm -rf /var/lib/amazon/ssm/ipc
service amazon-ssm-agent start
```

Comment: This breaks after a reboot. It seems that on start, the IPC directory is re-initialised.